# jogl program starting extremely slow

Tags: java, performance, jogl

Im trying to get a project with JOGL running and from second one I've run into problems. I have downloaded jogl-all.jar, gluegen-rt.jar and gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar and jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar version 2.3.2 from the release website of JOGL. I have extracted gluegen-rt.jar and jogl-all.jar, added them as a library to my project and put all the native files into lib/natives/windows-amd64. So far so good, I then set up a simple method doing the following:

```
System.out.println("Start");
GLProfile profile = GLProfile.getDefault();
System.out.println(profile.getImplName());
```

I hit the run button in IntelliJ and it printed "Start". Thats it. I started checking some logs, browsing the internet about that issue and suddenly, like 2 minutes later I realized in the corner of my eye that the output changed and it printed GL4bc. A little bit confused i thought this might be some IntelliJ related issue or so and started it in the command line. Same thing there, it consistently takes 1-2 minutes to execute GLProfile.getDefault(). What's this madness? I mean, I never choose Java for performance reasons, but that's a little bit too much :D.

What am I missing here? Or is this 'as designed'? Thanks for any help in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: Put `jogl-all`, `gluegen-rt`, `gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64` and `jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64` in the same directory. [This](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#IntelliJ_IDEA) might be interesting for you

Comment: I did everything exactly according to this page. Still, a fresh application with no code but `GLProfile.getDefault()` runs for insane 2 minutes. It attempts to run dozens of files named like `jogam_exe_tst<some_number>.exe` in `AppData\Local\Temp` and then spends several seconds blocked in waiting for them to finish.

Comment: What about this [Hello Triangle](https://github.com/elect86/jogl-samples/tree/master/jogl-samples/src/helloTriangle), also 2 minutes?